# How to set variable value after "Print when Expression" from textfield returned true

Tags: jasper-reports, conditional-formatting

Using iReport I have a textfield with following "Print When Expression":

```
new Boolean($F{data}.doubleValue()<3 && $V{check}.intValue()==0);
```

My problem is that I only want to print this textfield once. For that I thought I can use a variable (`check`).

I tried to use this expression for the variable:

```
($F{data}.doubleValue()<3) ? 1 : 0
```

The problem is that the expression for the variable is called before the textfield checks its "print condition" and so the textfield never get printed.

How can I achieve that the variable value is set AFTER the textfield "print condition" returned true?

> I want to mark the first value which is smaller than a reference value

Comment: Why do you only like for it to be printed once? (repeating values?), maybe there is a built in function.

Comment: @PetterFriberg I have a list of ~300 values and want to mark the first value which is smaller than a reference value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I often use the parameter map (`P{REPORT_PARAMETERS_MAP}`) to store and evaluate custom expression depending on previous values and outputs

**Example** (return `true` if value `$F{X}<100` and it has never been below before)

```
<printWhenExpression>
     <![CDATA[$F{X}.doubleValue()<100?$P{REPORT_PARAMETERS_MAP}.put("X_LESS_100",true)==null?true:false:false]]>
</printWhenExpression>
```

This expression leverage the fact that [Map.put(K,V)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#put-K-V-) returns the previous value associated with key, that is `null` if never called, while second time `$F{X}` is below 100 it will return our previous set value that is `true`.

> **Note**: you do not need to define any variable.

Answer (score 1):

I found a workaround, but I don't find it a very good way, because my solution is related to the evaluation time of the conditions from the textfield and the variable.

So if anybody has a nice solution please post it.

---

I set the initial value of my `check` variable to `0`.

The variable expression looks like this:

```
($F{data}.doubleValue() >= 3)? 0 : ($F{data}.doubleValue() < 3 && $V{check}.intValue()==0) ? 2 : 1;
```

The "Print When Expression" from the textfield is:

```
new Boolean($V{check}.intValue()==2);
```